# Why can't my code run two panels at same time? it doesnt show anything when I run it, but it compiles

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jcombobox

Wondering why this code won't run. It compiles but doesnt show the GUI or anything for some reason please help! It's a program with 2, eventually 3 panels in 1 frame. If i delete everything i've done so far, but just keep the stuff for one combo box/one panel it works and shows/compiles perfectly.

Anyways here is the code!

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

    import javax.swing.*;

    public class FastFood implements ActionListener
    {
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel contentpane1; //this panel will include cheese burger, chicken sandwich, hot dog, pizza, and salad
    JPanel contentpane2; // this pane will include side salad, french fried, or apple slice
    JPanel contentpane3; // this panel will include coke, diet coke, sprite, ice tea, coffee, root beer, or water

    JComboBox maindish; //combo box for maindishes
    JComboBox sides; //box for sides
    JComboBox drink; //box for drinks

    JLabel fastfoodp1; // label for main dish
    JLabel fastfoodp2; //label for sides
    JLabel fastfoodp3; // label for drinks
    JLabel c1; // cost for main dish
    JLabel c2; //cost for drink
    JLabel c3; //cost for sides
    JLabel cost; //label to display the total cost

    public FastFood()
    {       
        frame = new JFrame("Order your fastfood!"); //sets up frame title
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);       
        //all of this code is for the maindish 
        contentpane1 = new JPanel(); //creats panel object
        contentpane1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentpane1, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS)); //creates layout
        contentpane1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5)); //creates border
        //next three lines of code set up the label to prompt user for main dish
        fastfoodp1 = new JLabel("Select a main dish");
        fastfoodp1.setAlignmentX(JLabel.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        contentpane1.add(fastfoodp1);

        //next code sets up the combo box options and adds it to the panel
        String[] MainDishes  = {"Cheese Burger", "Chicken Sandwich", "Hot Dog", "Pizza", "Salad" };
        maindish = new JComboBox(MainDishes);
        maindish.setAlignmentX(JComboBox.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        maindish.setSelectedIndex(0);
        maindish.addActionListener(this);
        contentpane1.add(maindish);

        //sets up price label for selected item
        c1 = new JLabel("Cost of Main Dish");
        c1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 0, 0, 0));
        contentpane1.add(c1);

        //next code is for sides

        contentpane2 = new JPanel();
        contentpane2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentpane1, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        contentpane2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        //next codes set up label to prompt user for sides
        fastfoodp2 = new JLabel("Select a side");
        fastfoodp2.setAlignmentX(JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        contentpane2.add(fastfoodp2);

        //next code sets up the combo box options and adds it to the panel
        String[] SideDishes = {"Side Salad", "Frend Fries", "Apple Slice" };
        sides = new JComboBox(SideDishes);
        sides.setAlignmentX(JComboBox.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        sides.setSelectedIndex(0);
        sides.addActionListener(this);
        contentpane2.add(sides);

        //sets up price label for selected item

        c2 = new JLabel("Cost of Side Dish");
        c2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20,0,0,0));
        contentpane2.add(c2);

        //next code is for Drinks

        //makes it visible
         frame.setContentPane(contentpane1);
         frame.pack();
         frame.setVisible(true);

         frame.setContentPane(contentpane2);
         frame.pack();
         frame.setVisible(true);

         frame.add(contentpane1, BorderLayout.WEST);
         frame.add(contentpane2, BorderLayout.CENTER);

         //next code is for sides       
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
    {
        JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox)event.getSource();
        String maindishname =(String)comboBox.getSelectedItem();
        if (maindishname == "Cheeese Burger")
        {
            c1.setText("$3.50 for Cheese Burger");
        }
        else if (maindishname == "Chicken Sandwich")
        {
            c1.setText("$2.50 for Chicken Sandwich");
        }
        else if (maindishname == "Hot Dog")
        {
            c1.setText("$2.50 for Hot Dog");
        }
        else if (maindishname == "Pizza")
        {
            c1.setText("$2.00 for Pizza");
        }
        else if (maindishname == "Salad")
        {
            c1.setText("$1.50 for Salad");
        }

        JComboBox sides = (JComboBox)event.getSource();
        String sidedishname = (String)sides.getSelectedItem();

        if(sidedishname == "Side Salad")
        {
            c2.setText("$0.50 for Side Salad");
        }
        else if (sidedishname == "French Fries")
        {
            c2.setText("$1.00 for French Fries");
        }
        else if (sidedishname == "Apple Slice")
        {
            c2.setText("$0.75 for Applie Slice");
        }
    }

       private static void runGUI() 
       {
            JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
            FastFood food = new FastFood();
        }
       public static void main(String[] args) 
       {            
            javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {public void run() {runGUI();} });
        }
}
```

Comment: You're more likely to get productive answers if you can narrow down the problem somewhat, or at least narrow down the code which might be responsible (making it easier for potential answer-ers)

Answer (score 4):

`BoxLayout` does not allow sharing of target components. Replace

```
contentpane2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentpane1, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
```

with

```
contentpane2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentpane2, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
```

Note the use of `contentpane2` as the target `Component`.

Don't use `JFrame#setContentPane` if you are adding components to various locations of the `BorderLayout` of the `JFrame`.

You will need to override `getPreferredSize` in the `JPanels` `contentpane1` and `contentpane2` to facilitate correct sizing using `pack`.

Also make sure to call `JFrame#setVisible` *after* adding all components to the `JFrame`.